# vsftpd: Uploaded files 0 bytes/stuck uploads

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, ssl, vsftpd

We do have multiple servers across multiple datacenters. They all run the same configuration of vsftpd, with ssl certificates created on the same day. All certificates are self signed, but did not run out of time, worked before the issue occured and were created far before. Some servers are on Debian 9, others on Debian 10. There are no firewall rules.

They were all working fine until some day last week, when users were reporting that uploaded files were either corrupt or not uploaded at all.

This error happens randomly. I myself could upload all files others failed with from home (Windows 10).

At work (Debian 10) im also facing the same issues. Yet, customers are joining with all kinds of devices and ftp clients.

The upload fails via web, as well as via ftp client, but only randomly to all kinds of users. Not a single user is affected by a full disk space, as its sometimes the case in questions I have seen on my search through the internet.

After some debugging, I found out that the upload is just stuck at the STORE command:

```
Tue Oct 29 15:17:13 2019 [pid 44321] [TestUser123] FTP command: Client "123.123.123.123", "PASV"
Tue Oct 29 15:17:13 2019 [pid 44321] [TestUser123] FTP response: Client "123.123.123.123", "227 Entering Passive Mode (321,321,321,321,182,14)."
Tue Oct 29 15:17:13 2019 [pid 44321] [TestUser123] FTP command: Client "123.123.123.123", "STOR UltraCore_v2.2.0.phar"
Tue Oct 29 15:17:13 2019 [pid 44321] [TestUser123] FTP response: Client "123.123.123.123", "150 Ok to send data."
Tue Oct 29 15:17:13 2019 [pid 44320] [TestUser123] DEBUG: Client "123.123.123.123", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, reused, no cert"
Tue Oct 29 15:17:34 2019 [pid 44437] CONNECT: Client "123.123.123.123"
Tue Oct 29 15:17:34 2019 [pid 44437] FTP response: Client "123.123.123.123", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
```

123.123.123.123 is the client, 321.321.321.321 the server IP.
As you can see, the upload fails after 20 seconds (timeout) and then recreates the connection.
At that point, the ftp client asks me to overwrite the file. Indeed there is a file with a size of 0 bytes, named by the file i was trying to upload.

Directory listing, downloading files and all other operations are working perfectly fine. Only uploading fails from time to time like this.

After reconnecting with the ftp client a few times and waiting for some minutes, the ftp client says "1 failed transfer". Looking at the server, its there in its full size then.
Yet, thats not always the case and only if I reconnect multiple times.